Docker login error: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out:gpg: skipped: No public key
I'm encountering an error when trying to log in to Docker Hub using the docker login command.
The specific error message is:
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `gpg: skipped: No public key
gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: No public key
Password encryption aborted
Any insights on resolving this GPG-related error would be greatly appreciated!
I have tried recreating the access token and accessing docker through the terminal several times
All the letters for my username were converted to lowercase

This is likely from a misconfigured credential helper. You can try fixing the credential helper (by setting up gpg keys), or the easy (but less secure) option is to remove the credential helper from ~/.docker/config.json.
